# Problem with flexbox column breaking after upgrading from bootstrap 3 to 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, upgrade, break, tile

We have updated our website from bootstrap v3 to v4. But our portfolio (tile grid) now has empty space in it (same code). While in Bootstrap v3 it filled up all space nicely with the tiles.

**Screenshots:**

[Incorrect with Bootstrap v4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE6UT.png)

While before it was shown like this:

[Correct with bootstrap v3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWaxp.png)

**Code Examples:**

`code`
example with bootstrap v4:
https://jsfiddle.net/82esox3v/

`code`
example with bootstrap v3:
https://jsfiddle.net/s0qa5u2p/

I have been trying whole day, but really I can't get it to work properly. Does anybody know how to fix this? I suspect that we need to add a CSS property somewhere..

Kind regards,

Bastiaan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap code of `version-3` is not going to work on `version-4`. Things have been constantly changing with newer version's especially with `flexbox`

Your code includes some `css` like `@media-query for (992px)` which already comes up with bootstrap class named as `lg`

I have improved your `bootstrap` code for `version-4` which is working in similar way as it is working with `version-3`

more `HTML` with less `CSS` but still `responsive`

JSFIDDLE LINK: https://jsfiddle.net/hrj874sg/1/

```css
.blog h4,
.other {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.blog {
  background: orange;
  height: 505px;
}

.other {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap Version 4.4.1 CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
      <div class="blog">
        <h4>1</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-12 mt-lg-0 mt-2">
          <div class=" other">
            <h4>2</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
          <div class=" other">
            <h4>3</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
          <div class=" other">
            <h4>4</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
          <div class=" other">
            <h4>5</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-12">
      <div class="other">
        <h4>6</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-12">
      <div class="other">
        <h4>7</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-12">
      <div class="other">
        <h4>8</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-12">
      <div class="other">
        <h4>9</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! I do see the spacing/padding behaviour is still a bit different than my original version, but I will see if I can fix that myself :-)